# What are the differences in the teachings of Gaudapada,Nagarjuna and Yajnavalkya?

Tags: vedanta

I don't see much of a difference between them. If there is someone who has understood it well can you answer it?

Comment: What type of teachings and teachings in which topic? Can you be more clear?